# Trying to customize stepper of a spinner field Sencha extjs

Tags: sencha-touch

I am trying to add a custom spinner logic to a spinner field I have. I have been able to customize the spinner in the "view" by using onSpinUp:.

I am looking to refer to the spin up step in the controller but I am not having success. I am unable to reach the debugger I have in the "spinner" function.

This is what I have so far, I am not sure what I am missing. Could someone shed light on this?
Thanks in advance.

```
`control:{
     currentTime:{ //currenTime is the itemId
     spinup: 'spinner' // spinner is the function name
   },
}`
`
spinner: function (){
     debugger;
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have added single quotes, and I'm not sure if you code looks exactly like this, but your control object should look like:

```
//currenTime is the item id so it has to be wrapped 
// with single quotes and it also needs a # prefix.
control:{
    'container #currentTime': { 
    spinup: 'spinner' // spinner is the function name
}
```

Check fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/uo1

- Note: You need to add `container #currentTime`, just `#currentTime` won't work. It's a known issue with Sencha Touch.